# How to access the NoneType type?

Tags: python

For example looking at the type of None, we can see that it has `NoneType`:

```
>>> type(None)
NoneType
```

However a `NameError` results when trying to access the `NoneType`:

```
>>> NoneType
NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined
```

How can the `NoneType` be accessed?

Comment: Interesting [None is a singleton](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/none.html#the-none-object)

Comment: why do you need it ?

Comment: on Python 3 it is `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Why do you need none type and not just None? None type is used for checking mostly. Maybe you are doing something improperly?

Comment: @furas For a validation method which looks at types only, not whether or not an object is None. I can check that the object is not None first, then validating it's type however would prefer to only use the type validation method and tell it to accept NoneType.

Comment: Well you can do type(some_object) == type(None) comparision at any time. Why don't you use that?

Comment: @user5676973 It's the equivalent of asking why I don't validate against `type('this is a string')` vs `str`.

Comment: Just do `type(what_ever)==type(None)` for this one instance.

Comment: why would I use type('this is string'), I'd use type('a')   !!

Comment: Or, you can do `type(what_ever).__name__=='NoneType'`

Comment: This one's cool +1 to that #dawg

Comment: Why do you have a validation method for types to begin with? Duck typing, my friend.. And there is already a validation method in `isinstance()`...

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi I indeed use `isinstance()`, simply need the type to validate against it. Whilst duck typing is great, it's a bit of a tricky one when relying on user input.

Comment: What is duck typing?

Comment: I am wondering why we use equality test ``==`` rather than use ``type(what_ever) is type(None)``

Comment: To the people still asking why not simply using `None`... Here is a practical application:
`typing.Optional[int]` in function argument annotations for example is converted to `typing.Union[int, NoneType]`. `None` does not work for checks because of `NoneType` is in the Union definition. Only this works: `type(None) in myunion.__args__`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, in Python 2, or 3.10+, you can import it from the [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType) module:

```
from types import NoneType
```

but it's not actually implemented there or anything. `types.py` just does `NoneType = type(None)`. You might as well just use `type(None)` directly.

For some reason, they decided to take the `types.NoneType` name out in Python 3, before putting it back in 3.10. On versions where the name doesn't exist, just use `type(None)`.

---

If `type(None)` shows `NoneType` for you, rather than something like `<class 'NoneType'>`, you're probably on some nonstandard interpreter setup, such as IPython. It'd usually show up as something like `<class 'NoneType'>`, making it clearer that you can't just type `NoneType` and get the type.

---

If the reason you want this is for type annotations, use `None`, not `types.NoneType`:

```
def returns_none() -> None:
    return None
```

Static type checkers special-case this use of `None`.

Comment: Might as well do type(obj) == type(None), rather than the hassle of extra code?

Comment: user2357112, any idea of how to import it in Python3? I get an import error in Python3: `ImportError: cannot import name 'NoneType'`

@user5676973 Mate you're missing the point.

Comment: Ya okay, I am missing the point, can you explain then? my answer seems to  be fine.

Comment: @user5676973 The question did not ask how to validate an input, nor did it ask how to evaluate a type of an object. The question was about how to access the type NoneType. You persistently focus on the previous points and ignore the main focus of the question.

Comment: user2357112, NoneType seems to have been removed as a type in python 3: https://bugs.python.org/issue19438. Seems that the only way to access the `NoneType` type in Python3 is the `type(None)` way.

Comment: @Dave: Oh, huh, they took it out. Didn't notice that.

Comment: @Greg, types.NoneType is now back as of Python 3.10.

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by @dawg in the comments, you can do

```
if (type(some_object).__name__ == "NoneType"):
  # Do some
  pass
```

You can also do

```
NoneType = type(None)    
isinstance(some_object, NoneType)
```

Comment: `NoneType = type(None)` is interesting for compatibility or something, but for branching `if type(some_object) is None` is better ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)).

Comment: I came here looking for what to do when I need NoneType as a key in a dict, but even then it seems to be preferred to do `type(None)` directly.

Comment: @Kevin Also if `some_object` is `None`, your `type(some_object) is None` will never return `True`.

Comment: @sausix, thanks. I meant: 
`NoneType = type(None)` is a nice, reusable way to work with that, but for branching, the recommended code-style is an identity check like `if some_object is None` ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)).